# Bound on elementwise condition number in Higham

Tags: linear-algebra, perturbation-theory, condition-number

In chapter 7 of the book "Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms" by Higham there is an upper bound for the relative error of solution of linear system in terms of elementwise error. However, in the formula there is a term $|E|x|,$ which I cannot parse.
[Image of the theorem on the page 123 with this term.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGA2m.png)
What does it mean?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Looks like a typo. I think it should be $E\,|x|$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut It does, but it is repeated in each relevant formula after that.